# Webstatistics site, log clientside (javascript)? or serverside?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, logging

I an beginning an web application to log web-statistics (web requests, pageviews, etc) for my customers. Today more and more people are using ajax. So my question is, what is the best way to log an user visit. in javascript? or serverside? and then, what do i need to log? the page title? or the absolute url? or need customers choose their own pagenames?

anybody some advice?

thanks in advance.

Comment: If you use JavaScript in client side, you would surely need to do the logging in server side.

Comment: I konow about that, its need to be putted in a database anyway. So when do i have to send the pagevisit, to my server where i store it in a database. on the client side? or serverside?

Comment: Have you considered http://piwik.org/ ? Or do you have some NIH issues?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the code in your client's pages, you could use [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/).

It's pretty complete but of course is not a custom solution some clients may want.